# PHP urlencode issue with a parameter in my string: "&notify_url" incorrectly returns "¬ify_url"

Tags: php, string, special-characters, urlencode

So when I use PHP's **urlencode** on the following string, there seems to be a technicality coming up which I **think** is on a reserved PHP word "**&not**".

The original string:

```
cancel_url=https://example.com/payment_cancelled&notify_url=https://example.com/order_notify
```

I get the following result using urlencode:

```
cancel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpayment_cancelled¬ify_url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Forder_notify
```

As you notice above, the '¬' special character it creates (just after the word 'cancelled'). So to me it seems the "&not" portion of "&notify_url" is an operator reserved operator word ("&not" in PHP?).

I have tried PHP's str_replace function after url encoding as follows:

```
$paramUrlString = str_replace('¬', '&not', $paramUrlString);
$paramUrlString = str_replace('&#170', '&not', $paramUrlString);
```

(trying the ASCII code for that special character too)

I've run out of ideas now. Please assist, thank you.

Comment: `&not` is not reserved in php. It is html-entity, same as `&gt;`, `&lt;`, `&amp;` etc, only without `;`.

Comment: Please provide the code where you are URL encoding. Also note `&#170` is not ascii, that is an incomplete decimal entity, `&#170;` would be the complete entity, or it could have other trailing integers `&#170#;`.

Comment: Applying `urlencode` to your data obviously shows another results.

Comment: That sould be because of your chracter set in mysql if its not an out coming url, you beter set true character set to insert data in database to get right encoded html.

Comment: @u_mulder the error in not putting a ; behind is noted. However the simple solution has been posted. Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

urlencode does not usually replace `&not` at all, but does replace `&` with `%26`. See example here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e9d62797d01f8162170e5ad5181e14fc339faa52

You could try replacing `&` with `%26` before urlencode.

```
$urlString = str_replace('&', '%26', $urlString);
```

Comment: Great simple solution. I guess I didn't think to do it as I thought urlencode might want to replace the %26 during encoding, however it seems it recognizes it as a url special character code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that anything in PHP is replacting the string `&not` with `¬`, it's that whatever you're using to view/display the data is doing that.

Given that the closing `;` on the entity is not required, I would wager that you're putting the URL into XML without properly escaping the entities. While `&` is the entity that conflicts between URLs and XML, there are more than that.

The simplest solution is if you're embedding a raw string in an XML document you need to call:

```
$string = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_XML1 | ENT_COMPAT);
```

The *best* solution, on the other hand, is to not create XML documents by hand at all. Use a library like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/DOMDocument) or [XMLWriter](http://php.net/XMLWriter). This handles not only the escaping/encoding of your data, but all of the other subtle complexities of creatings proper XML documents.